# Split date-indexed dataframe into dataframe with monthly columns containing relevent values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing monthly values of rainfall, indexed by the date. Here is a short snippet:

```
      date  ppt
      ...
2016-11-30  253.379993
2016-12-31  52.709998
2017-01-31  9.030000
2017-02-28  10.050000
2017-03-31  16.560000
2017-04-30  45.509998
2017-05-31  103.829997
      ...
```

I need to produce a new dataframe with columns for each month containing the values for each relevant month over the syudy period (20 years).

e.g...

```
    Jan   Feb    Mar   Apr   May  ...  
0   
1
2
3
4
5
...
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have tried this so far:

```
df.pivot_table(index=df.date.dt.year, columns=df.date.dt.month, values='ppt')
```

But it returns this error, despite me explicitly setting the index as datetime...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-9cc1ff01344d> in <module>()
     29 Trmm_1M.index = pd.to_datetime(Trmm_1M.index)
     30 
---> 31 TRMM_MONTHS = Trmm_1M.pivot_table(index=Trmm_1M.date.dt.year, columns=Trmm_1M.date.dt.month, values='ppt3')
 32 
 33 # Trmm_1M

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   3079             if name in self._info_axis:
   3080                 return self[name]
-> 3081             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   3082 
   3083     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date'
```

Comment: Hi @SHV_la, could you please post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Assign a column for month and year, and use `pivot`:

```
df.assign(month=df.date.dt.month,year=df.date.dt.year).pivot('year','month','ppt')
```

In your case, this gives:

```
month    1      2      3          4           5           11         12
year                                                                   
2016    NaN    NaN    NaN        NaN         NaN  253.379993  52.709998
2017   9.03  10.05  16.56  45.509998  103.829997         NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `pivot_table`:

```
df.pivot_table(index=df.date.dt.year, columns=df.date.dt.month, values='ppt')
```

```
date    1      2      3          4           5           11         12
date
2016   NaN    NaN    NaN        NaN         NaN  253.379993  52.709998
2017  9.03  10.05  16.56  45.509998  103.829997         NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `df.pivot_table(index=df.date.dt.day, columns=df.date.dt.month, values='ppt')`?

Comment: Possibly.  He mentions that his range spans 20 years, so I used that as the index, but he'd need to clarify what the index is supposed to be.

Comment: Yeah, I interpreted it as year as well, since the date in the original dataframe seems to be month's end only anyways, but the method would be the same if OP wanted to use day

Comment: Yes I do mean years, sorry I will edit that. @Graipher, unfortunately I get an error, please see edit to come as it is too long for a comment...

Comment: @Graipher I had already done this, which is puzzling... see edit

Comment: @SHV_la: Did you try `df.index...`, instead of `df.date...`?

Comment: @Graipher yes I did, how I did this is in the error traceback, and I also tried using index  in your suggested code, too

Answer (score 0):

After not being able to carry out the above suggestions, I have managed to figure out a work around. While it involves more steps, the frustration of not being able to figure out what was wrong far surpasses the effort of additional lines of code...

```
df['M'] = df.index.month  #extracting month and years and creating new columns
df['Y'] = df.index.year
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(index=df.Y, columns=df.M, values='ppt') #pivot with these columns, rather than the index
```

Thanks for your suggestions nonetheless, everyone :)